# How to save continually the countdown number of days in the database in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am developing an insurance car web app where the customer can come and block his insurance at any time if the car has a problem.
I would like to count daily and save in the database the number of days remaining, and also if the customer blocks his insurance, that I can stop counting until he comes to activate it.

At the moment, I can only save when the customer blocks or unblocks their insurance via the insurance contract modification function.
Here is the update contract function:

```
def ContratUpdate(request, id=None):
    context = {}
    detail = get_object_or_404(Contrat, id=id)
    contract = request.POST.get('numero_de_contrat')
    form = ContratAddFrom(request.POST or None, instance=detail)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        id = form.instance.id
        contrats=Contrat.objects.filter(numero_de_contrat=contract)
        for contrat in contrats:
            if contrat.statut_assurance =='Reprise':
                nb_Days = contrat.nombre_de_mois+contrat.created.day-date.today().day
                contrat.remainingdays=nb_Days
                contrats.update(remainingdays=nb_Days)
            elif contrat.statut_assurance=='Suspendre':
                nb_Days = contrat.remainingdays+contrat.created.day-contrat.modified.day
                contrat.remainingdays=nb_Days
                contrats.update(remainingdays=nb_Days)
        return redirect('assurance_auto:Contrat_Liste')
    else:
        form = ContratAddFrom(instance=detail)
    context["form"] = form
    return render(request, 'auto/UpdateContrat.html', context)
```

And this is what I am trying to do in the contract model in order to solve my issue but it does not working:

```
class Contrat(models.Model):
    Statut_contrat = (
        ('Encours', 'Encours'),
        ('Suspendre', 'Suspendre'),
    )
    # numero_de_contrat = shortuuid.uuid()
    numero_de_contrat = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    statut_assurance =models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=Statut_contrat)
    vehicule = models.ForeignKey(Vehicule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Conducteur = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    utilisateur = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nombre_de_mois = models.IntegerField()
    montant_du_contrat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie_Contrat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    remainingdays=models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numero_de_contrat

    def activeStatus(self):
        if self.nombre_de_mois==0:
            return self.active==False
        else:
            return self.active==True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.remainingdays = self.nombre_de_mois
        if self.statut_assurance=='Suspendre':
            currente_date = self.remainingdays+self.created.day - self.modified.day
            print(currente_date)
            self.remainingdays=currente_date
            # super(Contrat,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            # return self.modified
        else:
            # nb_Days = self.remainingdays - date.today().day + self.created.day # Ce bout de code fonctionne à moitiés
            # self.remainingdays=self.nombre_de_mois
            nb_Days = self.remainingdays-date.today().day
            self.remainingdaysays=nb_Days
       super(Contrat,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Notice that the most important fields for my issu are `nombre_de_mois` and `remainingdays`.
The `nombre_de_mois` is the duration of the contract.
Anyone can help, please?

Comment: You're overriding save but not actually saving anything by calling super().save().

Comment: It might be easier to store the *date* of when the block ends; that way you can compute the number of days when you need it w/o needing to change anything in the DB.

Comment: I added super(Contrat,self).save(*args,**kwargs) at the end of the function but out of the if statement but still does not change anything in the database

Comment: @Melvyn, please check this now